# Не срабатывает событие keyUp в Safari на iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

В браузере Safari на iPhone не работает функция, вызываемая событием 'keyup'. Событие 'input' также ничего не дало.

```
var orderFiltersSpecialization = document.getElementById("orderFiltersSpecialization");
if (orderFiltersSpecialization) {
    var specializationLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".orderFilters__item--specialization label");

    specializationLabels.forEach((label) => {
        label.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
            orderFiltersSpecialization.value = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('input').value
        })
    })
    
    function filterSpecialization() {
        var filter = orderFiltersSpecialization.value.toUpperCase();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < specializationLabels.length; i++) {
            var txtValue = specializationLabels[i].textContent || specializationLabels[i].innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                specializationLabels[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                specializationLabels[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    orderFiltersSpecialization.addEventListener('keyup', filterSpecialization)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Не знаю почему это сработало, но сработало. Прикладываю код:

```
var orderFiltersSpecialization = document.getElementById("orderFiltersSpecialization");

    if (orderFiltersSpecialization) {
        var specializationLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".orderFilters__item--specialization label");
    
        specializationLabels.forEach((label) => {
            label.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
                orderFiltersSpecialization.value = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('input').value
            })
        })
        
        orderFiltersSpecialization.oninput = function() {
            var filter = orderFiltersSpecialization.value.toUpperCase();
            
            for (var i = 0; i < specializationLabels.length; i++) {
                var txtValue = specializationLabels[i].textContent || specializationLabels[i].innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    specializationLabels[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    specializationLabels[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        //orderFiltersSpecialization.addEventListener('input', filterSpecialization)
        
    }
```